# How to show the spread Type parameter and sub parameter in table html 5 razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a condition like, I have parameter and sub parameter in one column table named **"NameParameter"**. Parameter and sub parameter become one in that column but i have other column to identify if the value were parameter or sub parameter, the column is **"TypeParameter"** type int, if the value was parameter in **NameParameter**, the id in **TypeParameter** will be 1 and for sub parameter will be 2 in **TypeParameter** column.

and I want to make a column in table there a parameter and sub parameter, they are spread.
so here my codes.

```
<table>
<tr>
            <th>Parameter</th>
            <th>SubParameter</th>
            <th>Persentase</th>
            <th>Bobot</th>
        </tr>


        @foreach (var jajal in ViewBag.Coba1)
        {
            <tr>
                @if (@jajal.TypeParameter != null)
                {         
                    <td contenteditable='true'>@jajal.NameParameter</td>
                    <td contenteditable='true'>@jajal.NameParameter</td> 
                    <td contenteditable='true'>@jajal.Persentase</td>
                    <td contenteditable='true'>@jajal.Bobot</td>

                }
            </tr>
        }

    </table>
}
```

my expectation for output was like this

```
parameter    Sub Parameter 
a             e
b             f
c             g
d             h
```

but from my codes above, they were showed all value from column **"NameParameter"**
not yet spread by **TypeParameter**, so please help me with this. Thankyou

Comment: Is it a simple typo? First and second `td` both output `@jajal.NameParameter`

Comment: no, its not I'm suppose to make it same because the first "td" is for Parameter and the second "td" for Sub Parameter, so the @jajal.NameParameter, the "NameParameter" was Column name from my db table. I got stuck for the logic how to spread the value in column "NameParameter" to be parameter and sub parameter base on "TypeParameter", parameter was 1 and sub parameter was 2.

Comment: actually for spread it and loop it. hehe i got stuck for logic.

Comment: I see. Do you know in which order they (param and subparam) appear `ViewBag.Coba1` list?

Comment: I make the Viewbag like this  ViewBag.Coba1 = db.CIXMasterParameter.ToList();      its showing all data from the table.

Comment: for parameter its order from column TypeParameter identify as 1 and sub parameter in column TypeParameter identify as 2

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear how parameter and subparameter rows are connected, so it seems hard to display them on the same row. Lacking that, the best you can achieve is leaving one of the columns empty. Would look something like that:

```
parameter    Sub Parameter 
a             
b             
              e
c
              g
              h
d
```

Of course this is just an example. To do this, you could use some more `if`s:

```
@foreach (var jajal in ViewBag.Coba1)
{
    <tr>
        @if (@jajal.TypeParameter != null)
        {
            @if (@jajal.TypeParameter == 1)
            {
                <td contenteditable='true'>@jajal.NameParameter</td>
                <td></td>
            }

            @if (@jajal.TypeParameter == 2)
            {
                <td></td>
                <td contenteditable='true'>@jajal.NameParameter</td>
            }

            <td contenteditable='true'>@jajal.Persentase</td>
            <td contenteditable='true'>@jajal.Bobot</td>
        }
    </tr>
}
```

Notice how empty `<td>` is used in place of missing column value

Comment: i have try that way, its work but. the table look mess. it think i loop it in wrong way

Answer (score 0):

here my temporary answer, actually im use some code jquery.rowspanizer.min.js from  MIT license.

> 

```
<tr>
>         <th>Parameter</th>
>         <th>SubParameter</th>
>         <th>DetailParameter</th>
>         <th>Narasi</th>
>         <th>Jumlah</th>
>         <th>Persentase</th>
>         <th>Total Konvensi</th>
>         <th>Range</th>
>         <th>Risk Level</th>
>         <th>Bobot</th>
>         <th>Score</th>
>     </tr>
>     <tr>
>         @{
>             var isi = (List<APUPPT.Models.CIXMasterParameter>)ViewBag.Coba1; // Cast the
> list
>             var parent = isi.Where(x => x.TypeParameter == 1).Where(x => x.Parent_id == null);
>         }
> 
>     @foreach (var param in parent)
>     {
>         var subPar = isi.Where(x => x.TypeParameter == 2).Where(x => x.Parent_id == param.Id);
>         <tr>
> 
>             @foreach (var sub in subPar)
>             {
>                 var detPar = isi.Where(x => x.TypeParameter == 3).Where(x => x.Parent_id == sub.Id);
>                 if (detPar.Count() == 0 || detPar.Count() == null)
>                 {
>                 <td contenteditable='true'>
>                     @param.NameParameter
>                 </td>  
>                 <td contenteditable='true'>
>                     @sub.NameParameter
>                 </td>                  
>                 <td contenteditable='true'></td>        
>                 @Html.Raw("</tr><tr>")    
>                 }
>                 else
>                 {
>                     foreach (var det in detPar)
>                     {              
>                 <td contenteditable='true'>
>                     @param.NameParameter
>                 </td>  
>                 <td contenteditable='true'>
>                     @sub.NameParameter
>                 </td>                  
>                 <td contenteditable='true'>
>                     @det.NameParameter
>                 </td>         
>                 <td contenteditable='true' width='200'></td>
>                 <td contenteditable='true'></td> 
>                 <td contenteditable='true'>
>                     @det.Persentase
>                 </td>
>                 <td contenteditable='true'></td>
>                 <td contenteditable='true'></td>
>                 <td contenteditable='true'></td>
>                 <td contenteditable='true'> 
>                     @det.Bobot
>                 </td>
>                 <td contenteditable='true'> 
>                    
>                 </td>
>                 
>               
>                 @Html.Raw("</tr><tr>")   
>                     }
>                 }
>             }
>         </tr>
```

but the table is still mess. i got this answer from my senior.